# Ionic 4 "frame-ancestors *" error when trying to play Twitter video

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, twitter, content-security-policy

I am currently working on an Ionic 4 news app. I recently figured out how to properly embed tweets in Twitter cards, but this poses another problem. Whenever a tweet has a Youtube video attached to it, the video plays fine on every platform. If a tweet has a Twitter video attached to it, the video plays fine when I serve the app in Chrome. However, when I run the app on my Android phone and I press play on the Twitter video, I get the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/i/videos/tweet/……' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *".

My config.xml already contains the following lines:

```
<access allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media="true" allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content="true" allows-local-networking="true" origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-navigation href="android-webview-video-poster:*" />
```

I have looked at different ways to add HTTP headers to the call for the Twitter video, but I cannot get it to work. Now I wonder if I am even looking at it the right way.

Is it actually possible to play embedded Twitter videos in an Ionic app? If so, what would be the proper way to make it work?

**EDIT**: I still haven't been able to solve this problem, but I have accidentally discovered a workaround: in order to show ad banners I had to host the www folder of the app on an external domain. This basically converts the whole thing to a web app, on which Twitter videos actually do work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Fixed it bij adding `<access origin="https://twitter.com" />` in my config.xml to the android platform tag.

Looks like this now:

```
 <platform name="android">
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <access origin="https://twitter.com" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your solution, but no luck for me unfortunately. How are the Twitter iframes loaded in your app? Do you fetch them from an API somewhere, or are they hard-coded in the Ionic app itself?